# i am trying to make a chat activity in which users can chat personally.but some how only a singe data is been retrieve from the database

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to learn to create a chat Activity and trying to retrieve all the message from the firebase when I send the message then the message is been stored in the firebase but at the time to receiving on the single message is been received.i am unable to understand the problem my code

personalChat.java//onstart method

```
 protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    rootRef.child("Message").child(CurrentUserId).child(msgReciverId).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
          message cMessage = dataSnapshot.getValue(message.class);
          messageList.add(cMessage);
          messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

message_adapter.java

```
 public class message_adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<message_adapter.MessageViewHolder> {
    private List<message> usermsgList;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private DatabaseReference userref;
    public message_adapter(List<message> usermsgList){
        this.usermsgList = usermsgList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MessageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.coustommsglayout,parent,false);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        return new MessageViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MessageViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String msgsenderid = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        message Message = usermsgList.get(position);
        String fromuserid = Message.getFfrom();
        String fromMessageType = Message.getType();

        userref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User").child(fromuserid);
        userref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
              if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("image")){
                  String reciverimage = dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue().toString();
                  //Picasso.get().load(reciverimage).into(holder.reciverProfileImage);
              }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        if (fromMessageType.equals("Text")){
            holder.recivermsgtext.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            holder.reciverProfileImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            if (fromuserid.equals(msgsenderid)){
                holder.sendermsgtext.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sendermsglayout);
                holder.sendermsgtext.setText(Message.getMessage());
            }else{
                holder.sendermsgtext.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                holder.recivermsgtext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.reciverProfileImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.recivermsgtext.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.recivermsglayout);
                holder.recivermsgtext.setText(Message.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return usermsgList.size();
    }

    public class MessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public TextView sendermsgtext,recivermsgtext;
        public CircleImageView reciverProfileImage;
        public MessageViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView){
            super(itemView);
            sendermsgtext = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.sender);
            recivermsgtext = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.reciver);
            reciverProfileImage = (CircleImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_msg_dp);
        }
    }
}
```

it should show all the msg available in the Message.child(currentuser).child(reciveruserid). but it only shows the first value. Please help me out with this problem

firebase Message node

```
  Message
   JsmvpdGLjLbg9mQ0TfmKForis5q2
    PnYKrGiS7YUp9JdHNDMurOSbGBw1
    -LoHAND5o_T8S2NRECAH
     ffrom: "JsmvpdGLjLbg9mQ0TfmKForis5q2"
     message: "hello"
     type: "Text"
   -LoJCo9T7IrkHxD5xlZR
   ffrom: "JsmvpdGLjLbg9mQ0TfmKForis5q2"
   message: "whtsup"
   type: "Text"
   -LoJE04JSfl3BPyU3r9T
   ffrom: "JsmvpdGLjLbg9mQ0TfmKForis5q2"
   message: "wtsup"
   type: "Text"
```

Comment: If you set a breakpoint on `message cMessage = dataSnapshot.getValue(message.class);` and run the code in a debugger, does the breakpoint get hit multiple times?

Comment: Two other things: 1) please replace the schematic representation of your data with the actual JSON (as text, no screenshots). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data). 2) `userref.addValueEventListener` should probably be `userref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent`. It won't fix your current problem, hence posting it in a comment, but will prevent more problems down the line.